# Alternative to using "((type *)0)->member" in container_of()

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am using the macro `container_of()` in my code.

However its definition uses a `NULL` Pointer `((type *)0)` in arithmetic which brings up the error

```
pointer of type 'void *' used in arithmetic
```

Is there any other alternative to using `((type *)0)->member` or `container_of()` which doesn't use `NULL`.

The line in the code that brings up the error is this:

```
struct net_if_rx *rx = container_of(fq, struct net_if_rx, fq);
```

The real code is quite big. I'll put the snippet of the function that has the above line:

```
static enum qman_cb_dqrr_result cb_rx(struct qman_portal *qm __always_unused,
                      struct qman_fq *fq,
                      const struct qm_dqrr_entry *dqrr)
{
    struct ether_header *prot_eth;
    const struct qm_fd *fd = &dqrr->fd;
    struct net_if_rx *rx = container_of(fq, struct net_if_rx, fq);

    BUG_ON(fd->format != qm_fd_contig);
    prot_eth = __dma_mem_ptov(qm_fd_addr(fd));
    prot_eth = prot_eth + fd->offset;
    /* Broadcasts and non-IP packets are not reflected. */
    if (likely(!(prot_eth->ether_dhost[0] & 0x01) &&
            (prot_eth->ether_type == ETHERTYPE_IP))) {
        struct iphdr *iphdr = (typeof(iphdr))(prot_eth + 1);
        __be32 tmp;
        /* switch ipv4 src/dst addresses */
        tmp = iphdr->daddr;
        iphdr->daddr = iphdr->saddr;
        iphdr->saddr = tmp;
        /* switch ethernet src/dest MAC addresses */
        ether_header_swap(prot_eth);
        /* transmit */
        send_frame(rx->tx_fqid, fd);
    } else
        /* drop */
        drop_frame(fd);
    return qman_cb_dqrr_consume;
}
```

I have this for container_of definition:

```
#ifndef container_of
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) \
 ((type *)                              \
   (  ((char *)(ptr))                   \
    - ((char *)(&((type*)0)->member)) ))

#endif
```

Comment: This `((type *)0)` is not a pointer of type `void` it's a pointer of type `type`.

Comment: Please show us the _problematic_ code

Comment: I read it here that ((type *)0) basically means NULL? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207281/c-what-does-this-macro-mean

Comment: It's NULL but it's a _typed_ NULL.  In other words, it's a pointer to the given type with the object at address zero.  You'll get a SEGV if you try to dereference it but you can do arithmetic on pointers to members.

Comment: `((type*)0)` is a null pointer of type `type*`. No "basically" or other qualification about it -- that's explicitly set forth in the C standard.

Comment: You say you're "using the macro `container_of` ", but that's not a standard thing, so noone knows what you are actually using.  Show the definition of this `container_of` macro that you're talking about and there might be a chance of getting an answer to your question....

Comment: This code is embedded in squid source code which has its way to compile files. If I use it outside squid it compiles easily with gcc. However when I build squid, this code is compiled along with it and I get this error. Thus was looking for any alternatives?

Comment: Use __builtin_offsetof if you've got it.

Comment: I'm inclined to guess that you are misdiagnosing the problem.  The error message you report does not seem to correspond to the macro expression `((type *)0)->member`.  However, I could imagine some implementations of such a macro producing that error, for some compilers, in the event its pointer argument had type `void *`.  If that's the source of the error then either casting the argument to `char *` or modifying the macro is probably the right solution.  Without seeing the actual macro definition, however, that's pretty speculative.

Comment: Yeah, I guess ((type *)0)->member is actually not the cause of error. I think I'll have to change the macro definition as typecasting to char * also doesn't work. I crosschecked, no arguments are void *.

Answer (score 1):

The expected implementation of `container_of` is:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({               \
    const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr); \
    (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );  \
})
```

Note that we are using multiple gcc extensions in this code: [Statement expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238016/are-compund-statements-blocks-surrounded-by-parens-expressions-in-ansi-c) as well as the null dereference.

If we wanted to write strictly conforming code, we could remove the first statement, which only serves to provides type safety to the programmer:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) \
    ((type *)( (char *)(ptr) - offsetof(type, member) ))
```

This has the additional benefit of quieting the warning that you are getting.

Comment: Thanks. I used this definition but the error is still there. This code is embedded in squid source code which has its way to compile files. If I use it outside squid it compiles easily with gcc. However when I build squid, this code is compiled along with it and I get this error. Thus was looking for alternative.

Comment: `((type *)( (char *)(1 ? (ptr) : (type *)0) - offsetof(type, member) ))` is a portable way with type-safety.