# container_of() implementation in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rationale behind the container_of macro in linux/list.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083734/rationale-behind-the-container-of-macro-in-linux-list-h)

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                      \
        const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
        (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})\
```

Why do we need to construct `mptr` here instead of casting `ptr` directly to a `char*` ?

Answer (score 1):

Type safety, it assures that `mptr` is of the same type as pointer to `member` instead of just casting. If it's not you will get a warning.

Comment: you probably mean that `ptr` has the type pointer to the type of `member`, don't you?

Comment: @JensGustedt yup, fixed thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The macro as given in the kernel has a type check, namely it ensures that `ptr` has a type that is assignment compatible to the type "pointer to the type of `member`".

E.g if by accident `ptr` happens to be an integer, a cast would be perfectly happy to interpret this as a `char*`.