# malloc, recasting and free

Tags: c, malloc, ansi-c

I have some structures to store different kinds of lists:
typedef int db_int;
typedef char db_string[DB_STRING_LEN];

```
struct List_db_int {
    struct List_db_int *next;
    struct List_db_int *prev;
    db_int v;
};
struct List_db_string {
    struct List_db_string *next;
    struct List_db_string *prev;
    db_string v;
};
struct List_db_void {
    struct List_db_void *next;
    struct List_db_void *prev;
};
```

I also have an union which can store any of this list pointers:

```
union Uni_list {
    struct List_db_int *db_type_int;
    struct List_db_string *db_type_string;
    struct List_db_void *db_type_void;
};
```

I want to create a function which will delete some elements from lists but I want it to be list type agnostic so I come with following solution:

```
    /*data is an array of pointers to begin of lists*/
    union Uni_list *data;
    struct List_db_void *last; 
    for (i = 0; i < ELEMENTS_; i++) {
        last = data[i].db_type_void->next;
        for (j = 0; j < HOW_MANY_ELEMENTS_REMOVE; j++) {
            free_list(last, t->cols[i]/*type of column*/);
            last = last->next;
        }
        data[i].db_type_void->next = last;
    }
```

Here is the free_list function:
void

```
free_list(struct List_db_void *elm, enum db_type type) {
    switch(type) {
        case db_type_int:
            free((struct List_db_int*) elm);
            break;
        case db_type_string:
            free((struct List_db_string*) elm);
            break;
        default:
            /*Should not reach*/
            return ;
            break;
    }
}
```

But it does not work correctly and when I try to read modified lists, I end up with:

```
*** Error in `./ppbase': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f84aa47f678 ***                                                       
======= Backtrace: =========                                                                                                   
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x72ecf)[0x7f84aa14cecf]                                                                                   
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x7869e)[0x7f84aa15269e]                                                                                   
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x79377)[0x7f84aa153377]                                                                                   
./ppbase[0x402001]                                                                                                             
./ppbase[0x40217e]                                                                                                             
./ppbase[0x40273d]                                                                                                             
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f84aa0fbbc5]                                                                     
./ppbase[0x4009d9]                                                                                                             
======= Memory map: ========                                                                                                   
00400000-00404000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 10883382                           /home/hafron/dev/ppbase/ppbase                        
00603000-00604000 rw-p 00003000 08:04 10883382                           /home/hafron/dev/ppbase/ppbase                        
01797000-017b8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]                                                
7f84a9ec4000-7f84a9ed9000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 49858                      /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1                                
7f84a9ed9000-7f84aa0d9000 ---p 00015000 08:03 49858                      /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1                                
7f84aa0d9000-7f84aa0da000 rw-p 00015000 08:03 49858                      /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1                                
7f84aa0da000-7f84aa27c000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 9136                       /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so                                 
7f84aa27c000-7f84aa47b000 ---p 001a2000 08:03 9136                       /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so                                 
7f84aa47b000-7f84aa47f000 r--p 001a1000 08:03 9136                       /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so                                 
7f84aa47f000-7f84aa481000 rw-p 001a5000 08:03 9136                       /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so                                 
7f84aa481000-7f84aa485000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                                                                
7f84aa485000-7f84aa4a5000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 7209                       /usr/lib/ld-2.18.so                                   
7f84aa672000-7f84aa675000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                                                                
7f84aa6a1000-7f84aa6a4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                                                                
7f84aa6a4000-7f84aa6a5000 r--p 0001f000 08:03 7209                       /usr/lib/ld-2.18.so                                   
7f84aa6a5000-7f84aa6a6000 rw-p 00020000 08:03 7209                       /usr/lib/ld-2.18.so                                   
7f84aa6a6000-7f84aa6a7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                                                                
7fff249c8000-7fff249e9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]                                               
7fff249fe000-7fff24a00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]                                                
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]                                            
zsh: abort (core dumped)  ./ppbase < tests/filter
```

How should I use free function in this code correctly? Can I safly cast any of the List into: db_type_void->next (line 5 in second example)?

Comment: free takes a `void *`, so there's no need to cast.

Comment: you do not need to worry about type ,malloc gives you a void pointer so just delete that pointer no need of typecasting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function:

```
free_list(struct List_db_void *elm, enum db_type type) {
    switch(type) {
        case db_type_int:
            free((struct List_db_int*) elm);
            break;
        case db_type_string:
            free((struct List_db_string*) elm);
            break;
        default:
            /*Should not reach*/
            return ;
            break;
    }
}
```

is exactly the same as (considering that we never go through the `default` branch, as your  comment suggests)

```
free_list(struct List_db_void *elm, enum db_type type) {
    free(elm);
}
```

Pointer casts are for the type system and have *no* dynamic semantics. They disappear after compiling, so to speak.

This being said I'm taking a look to see what causes the segfault.

**EDIT:** Probably this!

```
for (j = 0; j < HOW_MANY_ELEMENTS_REMOVE; j++) {
    free_list(last, t->cols[i]/*type of column*/);
    last = last->next;
}
```

You're using `last` after freeing it. Do something like

```
for (j = 0; j < HOW_MANY_ELEMENTS_REMOVE; j++) {
    struct List_db_void *temp = last->next; 

    free_list(last, t->cols[i]/*type of column*/);
    last = temp;
}
```

Comment: But does free(elm) would work correctly (does it know that there is different size when it's List_db_int and List_db_string)?

Comment: @hafron. You always call `free` with a pointer returned by `malloc`. malloc keeps track of that size! You _are_ usign malloc, right?

Comment: When I use the temp as you suggested I have no longer problems with invalid memory but my program  seg faults now. But I think that it's caused by some other part of it.

Comment: Pointer casts do not always disappear after compiling. Some C implementations use different representations for different kinds of pointers, and they must be converted during execution. (However, passing a pointer to `free` will implicitly convert it to `void *`.)

Answer (score 2):

```
        free_list(last, t->cols[i]/*type of column*/);
        last = last->next;
```

seems to be incorrect.  `free_list` frees `last` which is accessed in the next line.

EDIT:

Regarding

> Can I safly cast any of the List into: db_type_void->next

It is not clean. C standard guarantees only that first member of a struct is at offset `0`. So, casting `->next` to the typed `struct List_db_string *` is ok.  But there is no guarantee that `struct List_db_string *` and `struct List_db_void *` have the same internal representation so that

```
        struct List_db_void *next;
        next = last->next;  /* was last = last->next in question */
```

can cause problems (theoretically; it will probably do the right thing on every relevant platform).

A more clean way would be casting `last->next` to the correct type and accessing its `next` attribute.

NOTE: all this is valid for accessing `next`; behaviour for other members (`prev`, `v`) is undefined without the mentioned cast.

EDIT:

Implementing operations on a generic type like

```
struct list_head {
    struct list_head *next;
    struct list_head *prev;
}
```

allows e.g.

```
struct List_db_int {
    struct list_head head;
    int v;
}

struct List_db_string {
    string v;
    struct list_head head;
}
```

(note the different order of attributs). You can calculate the object from `head` by using a [container_of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083734/rationale-behind-the-container-of-macro-in-linux-list-h) pattern.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am speaking about casts only (e.g. iterating without freeing by `last = last->next`). I will clearify it

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean: The different structs will have the same layout in common C implementations, so the union will not be a problem. `free` is not involved.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is the following pair of lines

```
free_list(last, t->cols[i]/*type of column*/);
last = last->next;
```

This code is freeing the memory for `last` and then immediately using that freed memory on the next line.  The caching of the `next` pointer should be done before you free `last`.

I'm unsure if this is causing your segfault but it's definitely something that should change.  My suspicion is that the error is most likely in the allocation function.  Could you post that?